# Why can't I get KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN in some situation in Android?

Tags: android, keyevent, event-dispatch-thread

Normally,when I press one key, I can get two action: `ACTION_DOWN` `ACTION_UP`, but today I meet a situation, when I press `right direction` in remote control, I cannot get action `ACTION_DOWN` in `dispatchKeyEvent(event)`, just get an action `ACTION_UP`.

Is it because some other methods has interception this event?

---

In fact the code of dispatch is the source code in `HorizontalScrollView` `executeKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)` method:

```
if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
                    if (!event.isAltPressed()) {
                        handled = arrowScroll(View.FOCUS_LEFT);
                    } else {
                        handled = fullScroll(View.FOCUS_LEFT);
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
                    if (!event.isAltPressed()) {
                        handled = arrowScroll(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
                    } else {
                        handled = fullScroll(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE:
                    pageScroll(event.isShiftPressed() ? View.FOCUS_LEFT : View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Might be good to post your code.

Comment: @JASONGPETERSON the code is added. But I don't think the code will help you understand my strange situation.